# R1C1 Formula Notation and External Workbook References

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

Problem: When creating a VBA script to dynamically insert formulas into a sheet's cells, I've chosen to use R1C1 notation for the cell references in the current sheet (because their locations aren't fixed between files used), and a fixed reference to a specific column in a separate workbook. This fails because Excel is adding unexpected parentheses around the column letters of the external workbook location.

EXAMPLE:

```
Range(FormulaCol & FormulaRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(MATCH(RC[-4],'[" & ExternalFileNameVariable & "]Sheetname'!B:B,0),"""")"
```

When the formula is output into my target sheet the script is working on, the formula comes out looking like this:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(BG44,'[filename.xlsx]sheetname'!B:(B),0),"")
```

The B:(B) ultimately results in the formula failing. I cannot use a variable reference since the location of the columns in my working spreadsheet will vary, but the columns' location in the external worksheet will be fixed.

I have to do this for several formulas. The only alternatives I can think of to address this are to create dedicated variables for the columns in the working spreadsheet I'm referencing and using FIND methods to locate each column's header and saving its column location to a variable... but I swear, there's got to be a better way.

Comment: `B:B` is not an R1C1-format reference - you can't mix types in the same formula.  Do you want `C2` there?

Comment: I'm aware I can't mix -- I suppose the question here is: How do I make a reference to a fixed column in another spreadsheet when I'm using R1C1 formatting for the purpose of targeting moving ranges in my main sheet?

Comment: I think `B:B` is `C2` in R1C1 notation (without the `[]` it's a fixed range) In the Immediate pane `? Range("B:B").Address(true,true,xlR1C1)` gives `C2`